In an Excel Pivot, is it possible to modify the subtotal values based on average values to be a sum rather than an average of all averages?
Tricky one to explain but is it possible to change the way that excel is applying subtotals to a pivot? My pivot is calculating the average earnings by Client and Source. But, when applying subtotals, it is averaging out the average amount by Client and Source. Is it possible to change that logic so it sums each average?

As I don't want to add any additional columns or calculations, my desired result is, really only relevant in Client D and E in my example:


I don't believe you can change the logic of how the subtotals are generated. Considering adding your data to the data model, and then you can possibly use DAX measures to SUM your averages.

As Ron and Michal had mentioned, it doesn't look like one could customize subtotals (I also tried).
Though your requirement is

I don't want to add any additional columns or calculations

here's an attempt using formula (requires Microsoft 365); I copied and pasted pivot table's format to the result.
=LET(
    u_periods, TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(--Table2[Date], 0)))),
    avg_per_period, LAMBDA(cur_cl, cur_src,
        MAP(
            u_periods,
            LAMBDA(p,
                AVERAGE(
                    FILTER(
                        --Table2[Earning],
                        (Table2[Client] = cur_cl) *
                            (Table2[Source] = cur_src) *
                            (EOMONTH(--Table2[Date], 0) = p),
                        0
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    avg_per_source, LAMBDA(cur_cl,
        LET(
            src_averages, DROP(
                REDUCE(
                    "Sum & Avg for cur_cl: per source, per period",
                    SORT(
                        UNIQUE(
                            FILTER(Table2[Source], Table2[Client] = cur_cl)
                        )
                    ),
                    LAMBDA(acc_src, cur_src,
                        VSTACK(
                            acc_src,
                            HSTACK(cur_src, avg_per_period(cur_cl, cur_src))
                        )
                    )
                ),
                1
            ),
            sum_src_averages, BYCOL(DROP(src_averages, , 1), SUM),
            VSTACK(HSTACK(cur_cl, sum_src_averages), src_averages)
        )
    ),
    REDUCE(
        HSTACK(
            "Sum of Avg Per Client, Avg Per Source",
            TEXT(u_periods, "yyyy-mm")
        ),
        SORT(UNIQUE(Table2[Client])),
        LAMBDA(acc_cl, cur_cl, VSTACK(acc_cl, avg_per_source(cur_cl)))
    )
)

If you get an error:
Using SUM in the manner ("eta reduced lambda functions") as in BYCOL(DROP(src_averages, , 1), SUM) may not be available your version of Excel (yet), so if you get an error  please try with:
sum_src_averages, BYCOL(DROP(src_averages, , 1),LAMBDA(c, SUM(c)))



Impressive, I couldn't make it work.

Thank you @Michal, I wonder why - BYCOL(DROP(src_averages, , 1), SUM) didn't work on my Mac until I got the Insider's edition. I'll add a note alternative. If you have time, please give me a hint about how to troubleshoot.

I don't believe you can do it with a pivot table but it's definitely doable with a formula or Power Query:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(Source, {"Client", "Source"}, {{"Earnings", each List.Average([Earnings]), type number}}),
    PivotedTable = Table.Pivot(GroupedRows, List.Distinct(GroupedRows[Source]), "Source", "Earnings"),
    AddedTotal = Table.AddColumn(PivotedTable, "Total", each List.Sum(Record.FieldValues(Record.RemoveFields(_, {"Client"})))),
    UnpivotTable = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(AddedTotal, {"Client"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    UnpivotTable

